# PHP Regex to find and replace a string of 1 or more pipes with just 1 pipe

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to replace one or more pipes with just one pipe in a string in PHP.  The below attempt is not working:

```
$string = preg_replace('/\|+/', '|', $string);
```

Here is a sample of input and the desired output:

**Input**

```
only | 1494 | | | | | | Limit: None | | Enr: 22 | | | | | | | | |RE
```

**Desired Output**

```
only | 1494 | Limit: None | Enr: 22 | RE
```

Thanks in advance for solving this headache.

Comment: There are spaces between pipes, use a non-capturing group.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte : Post this as an answer

Comment: Wow I did not even notice the spaces!  No wonder.  Thanks so much @CasimiretHippolyte I would still appreciate a full answer though as I can't seem to escape the pipes correctly for some reason

Comment: I think this will do it:  $string = preg_replace('/(\| )+/', '|', $string);

Comment: Yes, perhaps you need to add the last trailing space in the replacement string.

Comment: You are correct.  Thanks again :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the pattern `\s*` to match the spaces.

This code does what you want:

```
<?php

$text = 'only | 1494 | | | | | | Limit: None | | Enr: 22 | | | | | | | | |RE';

$string = preg_replace('/(\|\s*)+/', '| ', $text);

assert($string === 'only | 1494 | Limit: None | Enr: 22 | RE');
```